# MongoDB database design with embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I have a few thousand strings (`items`) that I would like to translate. I have structured my MongoDB as follows:

```
@document = {:item => "hello", :translations => {:fr => {:name => "bonjour", 
:note => "easy"}, :es => {:name => "hola", :note => "facil"}}}
```

The :translations field can contain many more languages and properties. I would like to run queries such as retrieving all items with no translations for a specific language, or retrieving all items having 'bonjour' as a French translation.

I don't see how I can do this. Is there a better way to structure my database for these purposes? I am using node.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to run queries such as retrieving all items with no translations for a specific language,

```
.find({ 'translations.fr': {$exists:false} })
```

> ...or retrieving all items having 'bonjour' as a French translation.

```
.find({ 'translations.fr.name': "bonjour" })
```

> Is there a better way to structure my database for these purposes?

I believe that you have the correct structure. You will have to become familiar with the [Dot Notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that for your purpose the model is good. You need [mongo dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29), you can use `$exists` to look for `fr` and dot notation for bonjour -

```
find({ "fr.name" : "bonjour" })
```